# how can i solve this : error 404 Not Found

Tags: php, html

my view details button is not working,when i click it, i keep getting this error: Not Found
The requested URL /details.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
yet this view details buttons works in my local host.
how can i solve this?
the code is below

echo "

```
         <div id='single_house'> 

         <h3>$pro_inf</h3>
         <img src='admin_area/house_images/$pro_image' width='500px' height='300px' />

         <h3><b>Rent  KSH $pro_rent </b></h3>
         <a href='details.php ?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>View Details</a>
         <a href='index.php' style='float:right;'>Contact</a>

         </div> 

    ";
```

this is where the link is.
please help

Comment: Perhaps remove the space in `'details.php ?pro_id=$pro_id'`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove space between:

```
<a href='details.php ?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>View Details</a>
```

Like this:

```
<a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>View Details</a>
```

Space containing text can change href values like `details.php%20`